# Fast start for fdsink: first 5 MB async, following bytes synchronous

Tags: c, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I wrote a little HTTP video streaming server using GStreamer. Essentially the client does a GET request and receives a continuous HTTP stream.

The stream should be sent synchronously, i.e. at the same speed as the bitrate is. Problem is that some players (mplayer is a prominent example) don't buffer variable bitrate content well, thus lacking every other second.

I want to circumvent the buffer underruns by transmitting the first, say, 5 MB immediately, ignoring the pipeline's clock. The rest of the stream should be transmitted at the appropriate speed.

I figured setting the `fdsink sync=TRUE` for the first 5 MB, and `sync=FALSE` from then on should do the trick, but that does not work, as the `fdsink` patiently waits for the pipeline clock to catch up to the already sent data. In my test with a very low bitrate, there is no data transmitted for quite some seconds.

My fdsink reader thread currently looks like this:

```
static void *readerThreadFun(void*) {
    int fastStart = TRUE;
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(fdsink0), "sync", FALSE, NULL);
    for(uint64_t position = 0;;) {
        // (On the other side there is node.js,
        // that's why I don't do the HTTP chunking here)
        ssize_t readCount = splice(gstreamerFd, NULL, remoteFd,
                NULL, 1<<20, SPLICE_F_MOVE|SPLICE_F_MORE);
        if(readCount == 0) {
            break;
        } else if(readCount < 0) {
            goto error;
        }
        position += readCount;
        if(fastStart && position >= 5*1024*1024) {
            fastStart = FALSE;
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(fdsink0), "sync", TRUE, NULL);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**How** can I make GStreamer "forget" the duration the wall clock has to catch up with? Is there some "reset" function? Am I misunderstanding `sync`? Is there another method to realize a "fast start" in GStreamer?

Comment: No one knows a solution to send the first X MB immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not quite the solution I was looking for:

> [`gst_base_sink_set_ts_offset`](http://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer-libs/unstable/GstBaseSink.html#gst-base-sink-set-ts-offset)`(GST_BASE_SINK(fdsink0), -10ll*1000*1000*1000);`

The sink will stream the first 10 seconds immediately.